# How to handle one image for all different resolution of android mobiles?

Tags: android

I want to place three button images of same size equal to screen it is working fine in size 320 x 480,it occupies full 320 size but android is having different resolutions of phones of different sizes 480 x 800 and 240 x 320 how I has to place same image for all resolutions equally to occupy full screen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) in the developer site